# Is income from youtube considered as freelance income?

Tags: germany

[Tangentially related](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/73719/is-it-legal-to-earn-money-from-youtube-as-a-bluecard-holder-in-germany). I ask ebecause I know in general freelance work is not taxed, so does youtube income count as freelance income?

[Related](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/27038/is-it-permitted-to-work-as-a-freelancer-on-upwork-while-studying-in-germany), and [also this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/27038/is-it-permitted-to-work-as-a-freelancer-on-upwork-while-studying-in-germany)

Comment: In the U.S.: it is my impression that freelance income is taxed just as any other earned income.

Comment: @paulgarrett - indeed, any income needs to be reported. Being 'freelance' does not magically make it not be income.

Comment: It is likely that monetizing Youtube videos would be a commercial activity, just like showing ads on a website. This would require registering a business (*Gewerbe*, not the tax-advantaged *Freiberuf*!). For example, one might register as a sole proprietor (Einzelunternehmer). But in any case, that is taxable income. There is no tax exemption for "freelance income".

Comment: *"I know in general freelance work is not taxed"*. In UK 'freelance' means 'self-employed' which requires accounts to be submitted to HMRC and tax on the income (less allowable expenditure) to be paid. *All* income is taxable apart from specific exemptions. The bottom line usually is that **you must keep accounts**. Apart from the legal requirement, without them you don't have a leg to stand on when examined.

Comment: "I know in general freelance work is not taxed" what? In which parallel universe would that be? What would keep every single person in Germany to quit their job and be rehired as a freelancer, if that means there are no taxes?

Comment: That was actually a typo @nvoigt

Comment: My suspicion is that your misapprehension about freelance work not being taxed is due to situations in which someone's country of citizenship does not impose income taxes on income earned outside that country. But, usually all income is taxed in some way by somebody.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by “youtube income”? Who is giving you something, a reward (goods, money, shelter, etc.) for what?

Comment: @KaiBurghardt Youtube allows you to monetize videos by displaying ads and receiving a share of the ad revenue if you have more than 1000 subscribers and more than 4000 hours of accumulated viewing time for your videos. Also there is stuff like sponsorship deals etc.

Comment: While I have written a somewhat comprehensive answer I think, I wonder if this is a good place for this question. Shouldn't this rather go on the personal finances stack?

Comment: @EikePierstorff I see. And is this revenue stream generated abroad? (→DTA?) Or is a/the YouTube Germany division the business partner?

Comment: @KaiBurghardt Payment is via a connected Adsense account, contract seems to be with Google Ireland Ltd (I do not do this myself, and Google is remarkably oblique in their documentation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freelance work is taxed in Germany, § 2 Ⅰ 1 No. 3 EStG. What is not taxed is income from a hobby, if the income is occasional and if making money is not the primary goal of the hobby. So the question has to be answered on a case by case basis.

The question arises often enough that the German Federal Ministry of Finance has published a PDF document with guidelines: ["I am Influencer. Do I have to pay taxes"](https://www.bundesfinanzministerium.de/Content/DE/Standardartikel/Themen/Steuern/Steuerliche_Themengebiete/Social_Media_Akteure/2020-07-30-FAQ-Ich-bin-Influencer.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=5) (German).

It lists the kind of taxes that might apply (Einkommenssteuer, Gewerbesteuer Umsatzsteuer - Income tax, trade tax and VAT).

You never pay income tax if your total (e.g. from all activities, not just the youtube stuff) yearly income is below the tax exempt allowance, § 32a Ⅰ 2 No. 1 EStG.

You have to pay trade tax if you make more than 24 500 Euro per year, § 11 Ⅰ 3 No. 1 GewStG.

If you work on youtube or other social media with the goal of making money ("Gewinnerzielungsabsicht") you have to do a "Umsatzsteuervoranmeldung" (VAT declaration). That is, if you write invoices to your sponsors, you charge them VAT, which however does not belong to you - you collect it and pass it on to the state. If you buy stuff for your social media work, you can deduct the VAT you pay for that from the sum you pass on. Note that you have to do the declaration even if you do not actually owe anything.

If making money is not your primary goal, and the revenue is small and irregular, then you do not need to pay taxes on your social media income. However there is no fixed amount that constitutes "small" income, that depends to some extent on your tax office (also if you do not pay taxes for it, you cannot deduct business cost from tax bill). As mentioned in a comment, monetizing your videos via ad views would be almost certainly considered a Gewinnerzielungsabsicht (since the idea is making a regular income), getting a bit of free stuff in return for a video not necessarily.

This is not legal advice, but personally I would not bother to report a few hundred that I make on the side over the year, especially if I get the money in non consecutive months (but then in my case a few hundred would not make a difference in any case). But if your income is high (thousands rather than hundreds) or regular (e.g. monthly for most of the year) you need to declare it on your taxes.

Comment: "k, you can deduct the VAT you pay for that from the sum you pass on." could you explain this

Answer (score 3):

### I know in general freelance work is not taxed

**Your “knowledge” is wrong.**

In general, **all** income is taxed.

Some jurisdictions may exempt certain income derived from hobbies that are not businesses but this is by no means universal.